# AS3 Parse RSS PubDate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rss

Other languages seem to have nice functions for parsing dates in many formats, or in user-defined custom formats.  I can't find the ActionScript 3 method for doing this.

I want to parse a pubDate from an RSS feed, like this:  `Wed, 26 Feb 2014 15:22:21 GMT` and turn it into a `Date()` object that can be manipulated for date comparison.

Or maybe more simply put: i want to convert the pubDate into an AS3 `Date()` object.

what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var s:String="Wed, 26 Feb 2014 15:22:21 GMT"
var d:Date = new Date();
d.setTime(Date.parse(s));

trace(d);  //Result: Wed Feb 26 15:22:21 GMT-0600 2014
```

Comment: that date string format is not supported/recognized by Date.parse(). that's why this is tricky. see supported formats here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse()

Comment: @split19 I run my example and works, I'm using Flash player 11.8. If don't work for you then build a function to parse the string

Comment: you're right. i guess i had something wrong when testing. that format is not listed as supported, but it does work. thanks!

Comment: FYI, AS doesn't seem to read the "GMT" correctly. in your example, @esdebon, the trace is a local time (GMT-0600), not real GMT. i had to make the string "... GMT-0000" to get the GMT timezone correct.

Comment: How do you parse dates in different formats in AS3? My date string looks like this: 2015-01-08T06:00:00

Comment: @Kokodoko Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140301/action-script-3-xml-date-format

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise I could simply replace the - with / :)